# Converting onclick event echo <<EOF into simple echo

Tags: javascript, php, buttonclick

I have the following `echo <<EOF` onclick event and want to convert it to simple echo, How can I do it:

```
    echo <<<EOF
     <button type="button"  
onclick="location.href=((document.getElementById('{$product->get_id()}')!=null) ? document.getElementById('{$product->get_id()}').value : '{$product->add_to_cart_url()}');" >
Add To Cart </button>
        EOF;
```

I tried concatenating but it didn't work.

How can I echo the onclick event with simple `echo` instead of `echo <<<EOF...EOF;`?

Comment: You should take a look at the [`echo()` documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php).

Comment: if what you posted is the actual, you should be getting a parse error.

Comment: This is as simple as `echo '...';` or `echo " content and escape double quotes ";`

Comment: That is a simple echo. Do you mean you want to define the string using `"` or `'` instead of HEREDOC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heredoc is useful when you have a string containing both `'` and `"`.

Having said that, here you go, just escape with backslashes:

```
echo "<button type=\"button\" onclick=\"location.href=((document.getElementById('" . $product->get_id() . "')!=null) ? document.getElementById('" . $product->get_id() . "').value : '" . $product->add_to_cart_url() . "');\" >
Add To Cart </button>";
```

Comment: Thanks that is working. However is there a way to remove `{ }` and replace it with `'.  .'` ?